Finding a simple form for a sum involving binomial coefficients
The motivation for this question comes from the quantum mechanical calculation of the ionization time $T$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
T = \frac{\langle t^{(1)} \rangle}{\langle t^{(0)} \rangle},
\end{equation*}
where $\langle t^{(\mu)} \rangle$ is the $\mu^{th}$ moment of the quantum mechanical amplitudes for excitation with $m$ photons and ionization with $n$ photons, i.e. Resonance Enhanced Multiphoton Ionization (n+m) REMPI.
Here, $\langle t^{(\mu)} \rangle$  is defined as
\begin{equation*}
\langle t^{(\mu)} \rangle = \intop_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} t^{\mu} \cos^{2 n}(t) \left[  \intop_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{t} \cos^{2 m}(t') {\rm d}t' \right]  {\rm d}t.
\end{equation*}
Inserting $\cos^{2 p}(t)$, expanded as
\begin{equation*}
 \cos^{2 p}(t) = \frac{1}{2^{2p}} \binom{2 p}{p} + \frac{1}{2^{2p-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} \binom{2 p}{j} \cos[ 2(p-j) t] 
 \end{equation*}
into the two integrals shows that $\langle t^{(0)} \rangle =  \frac{\pi^2}{2^{2(m+n)+1}} \binom{2n}{n}\binom{2m}{m} $. The calculation of $\langle t^{(1)} \rangle$ gives, amongst some other terms, the following sum:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S_{mn}} = \sum_{p=1}^{m} \sum_{q=1}^{n} 
\binom{2 m}{m-p} \binom{2 n}{n-q} \sigma(p,q) 
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\sigma(p,q)= 
\frac14 \frac{(-1)^{p+q}}{p^2 - q^2} \quad  \text{if} \quad p^2 \neq q^2 \quad \text{and} \quad -\frac{1}{16 p^2}  \quad \text{if} \quad p^2 = q^2.
\end{equation}
For specific values $m$ and $n$, the quantities $\mathcal{S_{mn}}$ and $T$ are easily calculated. For example for $m=1$ and $n=2$
\begin{equation}
T = \frac{\pi}{6} - \frac{35}{36 \pi}.
\end{equation}
Here is the question: are there closed forms for the sum $\mathcal{S_{mn}}$ or the time $T$ for arbitrary values of $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Fussy detail because there are two conventions for "$\Bbb{N}$"...  Is $0 \in \Bbb{N}$ in your setup?

Thanks for the comment. Here $n$ and $m$ describe the number of photons. Therefore, for physical reasons, 0 should not be included.

Latex:  There is $\langle t^{(\mu)} \rangle$, written \langle t^{(\mu)} \rangle ,which can replace $< t^{(\mu)} >$.

$\langle t^{(0)} \rangle$ is non-zero. I have included the value of $\langle t^{(0)} \rangle$ in the question (see above).

Partial answer: evaluating $\langle t^{(0)} \rangle$ only...
Henceforth assuming $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative integers (i.e., that $0 \in \Bbb{N}$), since this wasn't clarified in the Question.  For the following, as long as $m,n>-1/2$, everything works.  If we choose $0 \not\in \Bbb{N}$, everything below is unchanged.
Starting observation: The inner integrand is symmetric on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, so the result should be $f(t)$, (for some function $f$) on the first half and some constant minus $f(-t)$ on the second half.
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^t \; \cos^{2m} t' \,\mathrm{d}t'  =  \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} B_{\cos^2 t}(m+1/2,1/2)  ,&  -\pi/2 \leq t \leq 0  \\
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m+1/2)}{m!} - \frac{1}{2} B_{\cos^2 t}(m+1/2,1/2)  ,&  0 \leq t \leq \pi/2  \\
\end{cases}  \text{,}  $$
where
$$  B_z(a,b) = \int_0^z \; s^{a-1}(1-s)^{b-1} \,\mathrm{d}s  $$
is the incomplete beta function.  The piecewise expression highlights that the integral is a constant plus an odd function of $t$.
(Sketch: see problem 2 here.  I obtained this (on Mathematica 12.3.1.0 on Linux x86 (64-bit)) as ...
For $-\pi/2\leq t \leq 0$:
Assuming[{-\[Pi]/2 <= t <= 0, m \[Element] Integers, 0 <= m},
  FullSimplify[Integrate[Cos[tp]^(2 m), {tp, -\[Pi]/2, t}]]
]

-(Beta[Cos[t]^2, 1/2 + m, 1/2]/(2 Sign[Sin[t]])) if -(\[Pi]/2) < t < 0

Of course, on $[-\pi/2,0)$, the sine is negative, so we get the first piece above.  (I suspect that Mathematica is unwilling to simplify the Sign because at $t = 0$, Sign[Sin[t]] = Sign[0] = 0.  One may take limits at the endpoints of $[-\pi/2,0]$, obtaining the values given by the first piece above.)  Then, for $t \in [0,\pi/2]$,
Assuming[{0 <= t <= \[Pi]/2, m \[Element] Integers, 0 <= m},
  FullSimplify[Integrate[Cos[tp]^(2 m), {tp, -\[Pi]/2, 0, t}]]
]

(where we force the path through $0$ so there are no surprises from choices of branches of functions used invisibly by Mathematica)
-(1/2) Beta[Cos[t]^2, 1/2 + m, 1/2] 
  + (4^-m \[Pi] (2 m)!)/(m!)^2 if 2 t < \[Pi]]

Recognizing the $4^{-m} (2m)!/m!$ pattern, checked that the constant can be "simplified":
FullSimplify[(4^-m \[Pi] (2 m)!)/(m!)^2 
        == (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/2 + m])/m!]

True

giving the second piece above.
)
$m$" />
Then, using foresight to know what form we will need, for $t \in [-\pi/2,0]$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi/2}^t \cos^{2m}t' \,\mathrm{d}t' &+ \int_{-\pi/2}^{-t} \cos^{2m}t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^t \cos^{2m}t' \,\mathrm{d}t' + \int_{\pi/2}^{t} \cos^{2m}(-t') \,(-\mathrm{d}t') \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^t \cos^{2m}t' \,\mathrm{d}t' + \int_{t}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2m} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2m}t' \,\mathrm{d}t'  \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m+1/2)}{m!}  
\end{align*}
While we're here, let's get the special value, where $t = 0$ (so the two integrals in the above are the same and we only want half)
$$  \int_{-\pi/2}^0 \cos^{2n} t \,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{n!} \text{.}  $$
So let's hack on $\langle t^{(0)} \rangle$.
\begin{align*}
\langle t^{(0)} \rangle &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \; t^0 \cos^{2n} t \int_{-\pi/2}^{t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \; \cos^{2n} t \int_{-\pi/2}^{t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \,\mathrm{d}t \\  &\quad {}+ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \; \cos^{2n} t \int_{-\pi/2}^{t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \; \cos^{2n} t \int_{-\pi/2}^{t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \,\mathrm{d}t \\  &\quad {}+ \int_{-0}^{-\pi/2} \; \cos^{2n} (-t) \int_{-\pi/2}^{-t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \,(-\mathrm{d}t)  \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \; \cos^{2n} t \int_{-\pi/2}^{t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \,\mathrm{d}t \\  &\quad {}+ \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \; \cos^{2n} t \int_{-\pi/2}^{-t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \,\mathrm{d}t  \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \; \cos^{2n} t \left( \int_{-\pi/2}^{t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' + \int_{-\pi/2}^{-t} \; \cos^{2n} t' \,\mathrm{d}t' \right) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \; \cos^{2n} t \left( \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m+1/2)}{m!} \right) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m+1/2)}{m!} \int_{-\pi/2}^{0} \; \cos^{2n} t \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m+1/2)}{m!} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{n!} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)\Gamma(n+1/2)}{m! n!}
\end{align*}
Testing this with numerical approximations of the integral  suggests agreement.
Sort[{m, n,
    NIntegrate[ Cos[t]^(2 n) Cos[tp]^(2 m), {t, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
      {tp, -\[Pi]/2, t}, MaxPoints -> 10^5] -
    N[\[Pi]/2 (Gamma[m + 1/2] Gamma[n + 1/2])/(m! n!)]
  } /. {m -> #[[1]], n -> #[[2]]} & /@ 
  DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[{0, 20}, {30, 2}]]
]

we see the residuals are all tiny (format: $\{m,n,\text{residual}\}$)
{{ 0,  4, 2.951*10^-10},   { 3,  4, -7.05177*10^-9}, 
 { 3, 10, 7.36039*10^-11}, { 3, 12, 2.92314*10^-10}, 
 { 4,  7, -1.59812*10^-8}, { 4, 18, -7.12078*10^-9}, 
 { 6, 13, 1.51703*10^-8},  { 8,  2, 8.89517*10^-10}, 
 { 9,  7, -6.02441*10^-9}, {10,  0, 5.47561*10^-10}, 
 {10, 10, -3.50744*10^-9}, {10, 14, -6.89046*10^-10}, 
 {11,  4, -2.53506*10^-9}, {11, 12, -1.42945*10^-10}, 
 {12, 16, 9.66888*10^-9},  {13, 20, -1.10992*10^-8}, 
 {14, 7, 1.32268*10^-9},   {15,  0, -2.35939*10^-10}, 
 {15, 7, 5.87448*10^-9},   {16, 11, -6.35752*10^-9}, 
 {16, 12, -5.40399*10^-9}, {16, 15, -3.11025*10^-9}, 
 {16, 16, -2.20805*10^-9}, {16, 20, -5.10769*10^-10}, 
 {17, 1, -2.35397*10^-10}, {17,  3, -7.61136*10^-10}, 
 {17, 19, 5.95664*10^-10}, {18,  2, 2.56381*10^-10}, 
 {19, 7, 4.37891*10^-9},   {20,  9, 5.92969*10^-9}}

so I'm fairly confident that any errors in the above development are transcription errors.  The result seems to agree with the integral (on the values tested).
This sort of thing doesn't seem to help with $\langle t^{(1)} \rangle$.

Now, for $\langle t^{(1)} \rangle$.
Swapping the order of integration and handing off to Mathematica (again passing integrals through $0$ to control choices of branches in internals)...
Assuming[{0 <= m, 0 <= n, (m | n) \[Element] Integers},
  FullSimplify[
    Integrate[ t Cos[t]^(2 n) Cos[tp]^(2 m), 
      {tp, -\[Pi]/2, 0, \[Pi]/2}, 
      {t, tp, 0, \[Pi]/2}]
]]

(1/(8 m!))\[Pi] (-2 Gamma[1/2 + m] Gamma[1/2 + n] 
  HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1/2, 1}, {3/2, 3/2 + n}, 1] + 
  4^-n (2 (2 n)! (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/2 + m] 
    HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1/2 + n, 1 + n}, {3/2 + n, 3/2 + n}, 1] + 
    m! Gamma[3/2 + m + n] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[
      {1, 1 + n, 1 + n, 3/2 + m + n}, {3/2 + n, 2 + n, 2 + m + n}, 1]) + 
  4^-m m! Gamma[1/2 + n] Gamma[2 (1 + m + n)] 
    HypergeometricPFQRegularized[
      {1, 1 + n, 1 + m + n, 3/2 + m + n}, {3/2 + n, 2 + m + n, 2 + m + n}, 
    1]))

So, yeah, I'm not going to spend any time trying to derive that mess.  Converting to standard notation
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{8 m!} \left(
4^{-n} \left(
    2 \cdot (2n)! \left( \\
        m! \Gamma(m+n+3/2) {}_4\tilde{F}_3\left( \begin{matrix}1,n+1,n+1,m+n+3/2 \\ n+3/2, n+2, m+n+2 \end{matrix}; 1 \right) + \sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(m+1/2)  {}_3\tilde{F}_2 \left(\begin{matrix} 1/2, n+1/2, n+1 \\ n+3/2, n+3/2 \end{matrix}; 1 \right)
    \right) + {}\\
    4^{-m} m! \Gamma(n+1/2) \Gamma(2(m+n+1)) {}_4\tilde{F}_3\left(\begin{matrix} 1,n+1,m+n+1,m+n+3/2 \\ n+3/2+m+n+2,m+n+2 \end{matrix} ; 1 \right)
\right) -
2 \Gamma(m+1/2)\Gamma(n+1/2) {}_3\tilde{F}_2\left(\begin{matrix} 1/2,1/2,1 \\ 3/2,n+3/2 \end{matrix} ; 1 \right)
\right)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
where ${}_p\tilde{F}_q(\dots)$ is the regularized generalized hypergeometric series (denoted in bold at DLFM section 16.2(v))
Checking at sample points again
Sort[{m, n,
 NIntegrate[
   t Cos[t]^(2 n) Cos[tp]^(
    2 m), {t, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {tp, -\[Pi]/2, t}, 
   MaxPoints -> 10^5] -
  N[1/(
    8 m!) \[Pi] (-2 Gamma[1/2 + m] Gamma[
        1/2 + n] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1/2, 1}, {3/2,
          3/2 + n}, 1] + 
      4^-n (2 (2 n)! (Sqrt[\[Pi]]
              Gamma[1/2 + m] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 
               1/2 + n, 1 + n}, {3/2 + n, 3/2 + n}, 1] + 
            m! Gamma[
              3/2 + m + n] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 1 + n,
                1 + n, 3/2 + m + n}, {3/2 + n, 2 + n, 2 + m + n}, 
              1]) + 4^-m m! Gamma[1/2 + n] Gamma[
           2 (1 + m + n)] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 1 + n, 
            1 + m + n, 3/2 + m + n}, {3/2 + n, 2 + m + n, 
            2 + m + n}, 1]))]
 } /. {m -> #[[1]], n -> #[[2]]} & /@ 
DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[{0, 20}, {30, 2}]]
]

{{ 0, 20, 1.33295*10^-12},  { 1,  1, 2.93502*10^-9}, 
 { 3, 19, 1.10484*10^-10},  { 4,  9, 3.09878*10^-10}, 
 { 5, 15, 7.38116*10^-11},  { 8, 14, 2.51486*10^-10}, 
 { 9,  3, -5.0297*10^-10},  { 9,  6, -3.58024*10^-11}, 
 { 9, 13, -1.69378*10^-10}, { 9, 17, -7.12326*10^-11}, 
 {10,  3, -6.96522*10^-10}, {10,  6, 5.72617*10^-10}, 
 {10,  7, 5.2001*10^-10},   {10,  9, 5.90985*10^-10}, 
 {10, 13, 2.33617*10^-11},  {12,  2, -1.29489*10^-9}, 
 {12, 10, 7.36711*10^-10},  {13, 20, -4.22606*10^-12},
 {14,  7, 6.30264*10^-10},  {15,  2, -8.43004*10^-11}, 
 {15, 14, 4.10044*10^-11},  {16, 19, 9.85337*10^-11}, 
 {17,  2, -5.94007*10^-11}, {18,  3, -8.14977*10^-8}, 
 {18, 10, 1.92817*10^-10},  {19,  1, -6.34746*10^-10}, 
 {19,  9, 7.16343*10^-10},  {19, 13, -1.97671*10^-11}, 
 {20, 10, 2.47475*10^-10}}

These discrepancies are tiny so (up to transcription errors) the above are plausibly correct.
Then letting Mathematica churn on simplifying $\langle t^{(1)} \rangle / \langle t^{(0)} \rangle$ gives
1/4 n! (-2 HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1/2, 1}, {3/2, 3/2 + n},
  1] + 2 n! HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1/2 + n, 
  1 + n}, {3/2 + n, 3/2 + n}, 1] + (1/Gamma[1/2 + m])
m! ((1/Sqrt[\[Pi]])
  2 n! Gamma[
    3/2 + m + n] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 1 + n, 1 + n, 
     3/2 + m + n}, {3/2 + n, 2 + n, 2 + m + n}, 1] + 
  2^(-2 (m + n))
    Gamma[2 (1 + m + n)] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 1 + n, 
     1 + m + n, 3/2 + m + n}, {3/2 + n, 2 + m + n, 2 + m + n}, 
    1]))

which is ... certainly a result.

Thank you very much for your effort and congratulation on your result for $\langle t^{0} \rangle$.
Your result for the calculation agrees with the one $\langle t^{0} \rangle$ stated in the question, i.e. $\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)\Gamma(n+1/2)}{m! n!} = \frac{\pi^2}{2^{2(m+n)+1}} \binom{2n}{n}\binom{2m}{m}$, which follows from the identity for the Gamma function and the definition of the binomial.

Your result on $\langle t^{1} \rangle$ agrees with the one I obtained by using the sum $S_{nm}$ defined in the question:
$\langle t^{1} \rangle =  \frac{1}{\pi} \left(  \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \mathcal{H}_2(n) + \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{H}2(m)   + \frac{8 (m!)^2  (n!)^2}{(2m)!  (2n)!} \mathcal{S}{nm} \right) $, where $\mathcal{H}_2(m) $ is the harmonic number $\mathcal{H}2(m) = \sum{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k^2} $.
I wonder, if it is possible to find a more compact expression without using hypergeometric functions.
